# How do I find the density of a list of points given latitude and longitude in a 5 mile radius in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, latitude-longitude, kernel-density

I am trying to come up with a calculation that creates a column that comes up with a number that shows density for that specific location in a 5 mile radius, i.e if there are many other locations near it or not. I would like to compare these locations with themselves to achieve this.

I'm not familiar with the math needed to achieve this and have tried to find a solution for some time now.

Comment: So you want to find the average density of points in a 5 mile radius around a given lat/lon?  You should probably use geopandas

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i'm not super clear with what your problem may be but i will try to give you my approach.

Let's first assume that the area you are querying for points is small enough to be considered flat hence the geo coordinates of your area will basically be cartesian coordinates.

You choose your circle's center as (x,y) and then you have to find which of your points are within radius of your cirle: in cartesian coordinates being inside of a circle means that the distance of the points from your center are smaller than a given radius. You save those points in your choice of data structure and the density will probably be the number of your points divided by the area of the circle.

I hope i understood the problem correctyl!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).